# How do i reset JFrame after completing a game?

Tags: java, swing

So I made a TicTacToe Game and everything is working but I don't know how to reset the gameboard. 
Code:

```
public TicTacToeV1(){
/*Create window*/
window.setSize(300,300);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
window.setResizable(false);
window.setVisible(true);
/*add Buttons to the window*/
window.add(button1);
window.add(button2);
window.add(button3);
window.add(button4);
window.add(button5);
window.add(button6);
window.add(button7);
window.add(button8);
window.add(button9);
/*Add The Action Listener To The Buttons*/
button1.addActionListener(this);
button2.addActionListener(this);
button3.addActionListener(this);
button4.addActionListener(this);
button5.addActionListener(this);
button6.addActionListener(this);
button7.addActionListener(this);
button8.addActionListener(this);
button9.addActionListener(this);
}
```

This is the gameboard.

```
/*Restart the game*/
if(win == true){
int returnValue = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Play Again?", "Play Again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 0, null, null, null);
new TicTacToeV1();
}else if(count == 9 && win == false){
int returnValue = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Play Again?", "Play Again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 0, null, null, null);
new TicTacToeV1();
}
```

This is how i currently are resetting the game.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 new TicTacToeV1();
    }
```

Edit: i have not added a no option yet, so yes is the same to no.

Comment: You don't want to reset the frame, you want to reset all of the components in your frame back to their default state. I'd suggest creating a `reset` method which will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user defined `reset()` in that you can define the needed components default state.
And call the method where you want to restart.

Comment: Im not really sure how to make the `reset()` method. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that you have here. Both of these methods have been covered by the other answers but I will try to summarize them:

- **Create a new instance of the game**

In this method, you automatically close your previous `JFrame` using the `dispose` method and just start a new `TicTacToeV1` from the game restart logic.

- **Set all the components back to their original state**

With this method, you just make all the components look like they did at the beginning of the game. Without seeing the game it is difficult to say exactly what this would entail. It would most likely involve taking Os and Xs off of buttons and resetting any counters that you have.